# configure gearman php extension fail on MacOS - error: unknown type name 'zend_object_value'

Tags: php, gearman

I tried to use this instruction to install Gearman PHP Extension for php 7.4 on MacOS:

```
tar xzf gearman-X.Y.tgz
cd gearman-X.Y
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

and get error at ./configure

```
dev/gearman/gearman-1.1.2/php_gearman.c:1011:2: error: unknown type name 'zend_object_value'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it need to use version original php-configure.
For my case :

```
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.10/bin/php-config
```

solve the trouble

Comment: good you have found the solution, please accept the answer to remove your question from unresolved